# How to I make exe like steam games?

Tags: executable

I have an installation program(setup.exe). How to I make this setup.exe that can not be run directly like steam games?

If so, i want to non-double clickable setup.exe. This exe is executed by another exe(I will make this another exe in c++)

What should I do?

If you help me, I will be appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

steam is using windows shortcuts, and they are actually "web" links like that: "steam://rungameid/10090" instead of http:// ftp:// etc.. it uses steam://

but if you want to your exe executed by "another exe" you can use args[] that launch your program

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html

or if you just want to make a launcher for your program you can use windows shortcuts (just like steam), that ll work aswell

but I have no clue how to make your own "web" links like steam did (without using steam itself)